# Snackbar message doesn't change in real time

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to change some data inside a snackbar message, but the message don't change.

That's a little example for what i'm trying to do:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snackbar-qvxipb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

```
Desirable Behavior: 
Redirecting in 3s -> Redirecting in 2s -> Redirecting in 1s
```

Can someone help me? Thanks.

*Edit: Without have to open multiple snackbars.*

Comment: First way just move `this.snackBar` code to end of `setInterval()` function.

Comment: this would open multiple snackbars, i want to change it on the same snackbar =/

Comment: Yeah i know. Make Your own snack using directive or component. Snackbars are made to show one by one don't know are there is any option to prevent to do that.

Comment: hmm ok, thanks for your answer. I'll try that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that there can be a problem with 'MatSnackBar'. They will show up and disappear don't know if there is a configuration to prevent from that so i post an answer with solution using directive.

**component.ts**

```
export class SnackTimerComponent {

  timer: number = 5
  message: string

  startCountdown() {
    this.timer = 5
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.timer != 0) {
        this.timer--
        console.log(this.timer);
        this.message = `Redirecting in ${this.timer}s...`;
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval)
        this.message = null
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

**directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[snack-bar-timer]'
})
export class SnackBarTimerDirective {

  @Input() color: string = "#b5e7a0"

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    const style = el.nativeElement.style
    style.backgroundColor = this.color
    style.position = "absolute"
    style.left = "50%"
    style.bottom = "0"
    style.transform = "translateX(-50%)"
    style.padding = "20px"
    style.margin = "12px"
    style.width = "fit-content"
    style.borderRadius = "8px"
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```html
<button (click)="startCountdown()">Start countdown</button>
<div *ngIf="message" snack-bar-timer>{{message}}</div>
```